# Add option to query string before get_posts() is called on archive.php

Tags: filters, query

I'm developing woocommerce based shoppingmall.

I did add some 'post meta' on each product.

[image]

As you know, if we click shop page, and wordpress core query like this

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( 
SELECT object_id 
FROM wp_term_relationships 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (16) ) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, wp_posts.post_date DESC, wp_posts.ID DESC
LIMIT 0, 12`

And I want to add some condition like this

> get only product with '_user_request' of 'post meta' associated with this item are 'yes'

So, if some product's '_user_request' of 'post meta' is 'no', don't get this product.

How can I do this?

Comment: See [Custom Field Parameters for `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Answer (score 0):

```
function rpf_add_query_var_not_to_show_user_request_product($query) {

  $post_type = $query->get( 'post_type' );
    if ( ! is_null($post_type) && $post_type == 'product' ) {
      $query->set( 'meta_key', '_user_request' );
      $query->set( 'meta_value', 'no' );
      $query->set( 'meta_compare', '=' ); // default
    }
  }
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 
'rpf_add_query_var_not_to_show_user_request_product', 100, 1 );
```

yes, pre_get_posts is heaven! and $query->set(), $query->get() are angels!